# xml to svg dynamically

Tags: javascript, xml, svg

I have been searching for months now about this subject, but I can't find anything about it. What I'm looking for: I have sheetmusic on my screen, which is xml converted to svg  with javascript. Now I want to make buttons with which I can manipulate the SVG that's displayed on the screen. For example: the music has lyrics underneath the notes and chords above it. Let's say I want to replace or remove them with an onclick button. All this temporarily, only on the screen.

Comment: Show us what you've written and we'll try to correct it. We're not here to write it all from scratch, nor to act as a surrogate web search facility.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a similar project. You have 2 approaches:

1. Directly modify SVG (hmmm not cool if you have complex objects)
2. Find out which SVG element is to be modified, find the corresponding id
   in the XML structure, modify the XML node, "recompile" XML to SVG.

As a more performant way, you may compile only the node that changed and
then insert it in the SVG.

In order to select the element you want to apply an action on, you can set
a 'click' event listener on each selectable element.